# Chrome error when resolving URLs for the first time

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, dns

I'm frequently - roughly 20% of requests - seeing the following error when opening URLs for the first time:

Error 137 (net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED): Unknown error.

When I refresh the request, the URL opens correctly.

This only seems to be an issue in Chrome (ie, resolving URLs seems fine in other browsers). I'm using version 24.0.1312.57 m on Windows 7 64-bit.

Does anybody know the root cause of this problem and/ or how I might go about fixing it?

Comment: many solutions can found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/HFXT5JY-uuU[1-25-true])

Comment: If you try the same site shortly after, does it respond? That is a symptom of a slow DNS resolver, that one should build up a cache of site names over time, so unless you are hitting always different sites this can happen only if that one is rebooted too often. What is your network setup?

Comment: Yes, if I refresh the site, it usually responds. The network setup is just a home ADSL wireless router using DHCP. It seems unusual in that only Chrome is affected.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly an issue with one of your local DNS servers - you could try manually setting your Primary DNS Server to 8.8.8.8 and your Secondary to 8.8.4.4 as long as you don't need DNS for an Active Directory scenario. You might find that your router picks up you ISPs DNS server - try manually setting the DNS server to override you ISP's settings to elimnate that as a cause.

If you have an AD setup with a local DNS Server (or two) then look to set your forwarders to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 - it's also possible/probable that one of your local DNSes is slow at responding.

Best of luck.